# RStudio - blank screen on Mac

Tags: r, rstudio

I got blank screen in RStudio - it's first launch. Got already installed R, tried to reinstall, but it didn't work to me.
I already found a lot answers for Windows, but still no solution for OS X with the same problem.

OS X 10.10.3

RStudio Desktop 0.99.441

Comment: The same to me .R and RStudo I had already reinstall. R-3.3.1_0.pkg RStudio-0.99.903.dmg .I can run R .  Do you get the solution ? @htzfun

Comment: @wyx No. Actually, that was one of reasons why I gave up on R =(